# c# How can i replace backslash in a string?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, string-formatting

I am working on a c# project and have some strings like this

**first string**

```
"[\"2018\\/02\\/12\",[\"Test1\",\"Test2\",\"Test3\",\"Test4\"]]"
```

But this string format is not not suitable for my application. I want to change first string to this :

**second string**

```
2018-02-12,"Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4"
```

I've done some of it, but I'm having trouble getting a backslash. Actually backslash did not changed.

**my code :**

```
string MyString = "[\"2018\\/02\\/12\",[\"Test1\",\"Test2\",\"Test3\",\"Test4\"]]";
MyString = MyString.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace("\\", "");
```

How can I get the second string?

Comment: Are you sure you are seeing the **actual** string and not just the escaped string the debugger shows you?

Comment: Why dont you look at json parser instead?

Comment: You can use backslash with `@""` string literals. like : `@"C:\Windows"`

Comment: @P.Knowledge thanks, but dont work

Comment: Try using following code:

MyString.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty).Replace("\\", string.Empty).Replace(@"\", string.Empty).Replace("/", "-");

Comment: No one ever replied, and only negative!!!

Comment: Did you try the code?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani not work Unfortunately

Comment: You should open the result in Text Visualizer, on my IDE the result is same as you require.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Thanks, it works fine in Text Visualizer.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Yes, please be sure to reply in the answer to see the result in Text Visualizer

Comment: I have added it in my answer, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
MyString.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty).Replace("\\", string.Empty).Replace(@"\", string.Empty).Replace("/", "-");
```

And view the result in Text Visualizer.